# Why is STS Cask not available for macOS?

Tags: homebrew, spring-tool-suite

I tried to install Spring Tool Suite on macOS Mojave using **brew cask install sts** (which i found while googling), but apparently it is not available:

```
brew cask install sts
==> Tapping homebrew/cask
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3580, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3580/3580), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3572/3572), done.
remote: Total 3580 (delta 23), reused 592 (delta 6), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (3580/3580), 1.20 MiB | 1.25 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (23/23), done.
Checking out files: 100% (3560/3560), done.
Tapped 1 command and 3469 casks (3,585 files, 3.9MB).
Error: Cask 'sts' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.
```

Any idea if i can install and manage STS using Homebrew, under a different caskname perhaps ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used a wrong package name. The package name for Spring Tool Suite in Homebrew is `springtoolsuite`.

```sh
brew cask install springtoolsuite
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this latest :-

`brew install --cask springtoolsuite`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
brew install --cask springtoolsuite
```